# How to find matching datas from two json documents in couchdb?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchdb-futon

How to find matching datas from two json documents.For ex: I have two json documents and skills json documents.

In Skills Document:

```
{

     "_id": "b013dcf12d1f7d333467b1447a00013a",
     "_rev": "3-e54ad6a14046f809e6da872294939f12",
     "core_skills": [
          {
              "core_skill_code": "SA1",
              "core_skill_desc": "communicate with others in writing"
          },
          {
              "core_skill_code": "SA2",
              "core_skill_desc": "complete accurate well written work with attention to detail"
          },
          {
              "core_skill_code": "SA3",
              "core_skill_desc": "follow guidelines/procedures/rules and service level agreements"
          },
          {
              "core_skill_code": "SA4",
              "core_skill_desc": "ask for clarification and advice from others"
          }
      ]}
```

In Employee Document:

```
{

  "_id": "b013dcf12d1f7d333467b12350007op",
  "_rev": "3-e54ad6a14046f809e6da156794939f12",
  "employee_name" :"Ashwin",
  "employee_role" : "Software engineer",
  "core_skills":["SA1","SA4"]
}
```

Comment: So what is the data you are trying to match?

Comment: i need to match core skills data.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Create an index of the core skill codes and descriptions. Then you can decypher the codes in the employee records.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you want to do, but the following might be helpful. Assuming that the first data set is a list of skills and their descriptions and the second is an employee record, then assigning to variables with suitable names might look like:

```
var skillCodes = {
  "_id": "b013dcf12d1f7d333467b1447a00013a",
  "_rev": "3-e54ad6a14046f809e6da872294939f12",
  "core_skills": [{
      "core_skill_code": "SA1",
      "core_skill_desc": "communicate with others in writing"
    },{
      "core_skill_code": "SA2",
      "core_skill_desc": "complete accurate well written work with attention to detail"
    },{
      "core_skill_code": "SA3",
      "core_skill_desc": "follow guidelines/procedures/rules and service level agreements"
    },{
      "core_skill_code": "SA4",
      "core_skill_desc": "ask for clarification and advice from others"
    }
  ]};

var employee0 = {
  "_id": "b013dcf12d1f7d333467b12350007op",
  "_rev": "3-e54ad6a14046f809e6da156794939f12",
  "employee_name" :"Ashwin",
  "employee_role" : "Software engineer",
  "core_skills":["SA1","SA4"]
};
```

Creating a skills index makes looking for particular skills much simpler, some code to do that is:

```
var skillCodeIndex = {};
skillCodes.core_skills.forEach(function(item){
  skillCodeIndex[item.core_skill_code] = item.core_skill_desc;
});
```

Now all that is required is a function to get the skills for a particular employee, say:

```
function getCoreSkills (employee) {
  console.log('Employee ' + employee.employee_name + ' has the following core skills:');
  employee.core_skills.forEach(function(skill) {
    console.log(skill + ': ' + skillCodeIndex[skill]);
  });
}
```

An example:

```
getCoreSkills(employee0);

Employee Ashwin has the following core skills:
SA1: communicate with others in writing
SA4: ask for clarification and advice from others
```

The above could become much more OO given constructors for *skillCodes* and *employee* instances, I'll leave that to you.